# CSS does not work in inherited Django template

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have two page templates and a CSS file in static directory.

This is my main.html where CSS works just fine:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>  </title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg'%}"  height="49px" width="100px" >
                <li><a href=#> HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href=#> ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="rent"> RENT</a></li>
                <li><a href="sale"> SALES</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav> 

        {% block content %}
        
        {% endblock  %}
    </body>
    <hr>
    <footer>
```

This is my index.html where CSS **does not work**:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div id="showcase">

    <div class="section-main container" >
        <h1>House rent & Sale</h1>
        <p class="lead hide-on-small">This is a web application </p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please share more details: show your CSS file at least related part of it, elaborate what is "does not work" (which style not applied to which element). Note, there is zero css-classes applied to main.html elements so it's not clear even what "it works on main page" means.

Answer (score 0):

Move your  {% block content %}to above the header in main.html

Comment: its not working

Comment: Show your css in the question, clean main.html by removing footer and hr etc. endblock should come after </body>